# ggplot histogram fails inside shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, histogram

I am trying to plot a simple histogram inside a shiny app. Outside the app (in R script), the graph gets plotted without any problems, ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYhLQ.jpg)) but the same code produces an odd looking graph from inside the app ([see the wrong graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWW4k.jpg))

Could you help me figure out what's wrong? Link to dataset: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ITK0lTWm_mkb9KonHLq4nuKDv-PBUDeR

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(scales)
library(shiny)

# read data
cso_corruption <- read.csv("cso_corruption.csv", header = T, sep = ",")

ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       radioButtons(inputId = "x",label ="Measurement Type",choices = 
                      c("freq_business", "freq_cso"), selected = NULL)
                  ),

     mainPanel(
       plotOutput(outputId = "hist")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$hist <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = na.omit(cso_corruption), aes(x=input$x)) +
                                 geom_histogram(fill="lightgreen", stat="count"))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Why don't you post your output/logs or any other info we can use to help you?

Comment: When you say "code fails," what does that mean exactly? Are you getting an error message? If so, you need to share that information as well.

Comment: @ytpillai - I have edited the post and added the graphs. Pls help

Comment: @MrFlick - No error messages, just a wrong looking plot. I have added the graphs in the post now.

Comment: @umbi no I don't want to. JK, btw you are using histogram which has the bars stuck together. I would recommend checking that you aren't duplicating data in your renderPlot

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason is the data is not making it into the server.

I would put the csv into another file within the directory, so you can access it using

```
read.csv("./Data/projectdata.csv")
```

Therefore it does not get lost when you publish. Also make sure the data is checked when publishing. One last note to include the read.csv function in the server.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem here is not with publishing. The plot simply doesn't work when I run the code on RStudio. I have tried both changing the directory and reading csv within the server - doesn't help... and I am not getting any error messages, instead just a wrong plot.

Answer (score 0):

After many trial-and-errors, I have figured out a solution. The trick is, in the server, I used aes_string instead of aes. I haven't figured out why aes_string works here, since it is supposed to require the variables to be passed in quotes. But it works for some reason.